# Why 32 bit and 64 bit Android application give different /proc/cpuinfo : feature list

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture

We have Android 32 and 64 bit variant of our application and when we try to read /proc/cpuinfo we get different value of "features".

For eg. If 64 bit application reads /proc/cpuinfo value of feature, then we are getting "fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32". Same 32 bit application give "half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32"

We have tried executing these application on multiple version of Android as well multiple phones of different brands. The result is same that cpuinfo is different for 32 and 64 bit application.

Answer (score 0):

/proc/cpuinfo is a read-only file on the device itself.  It differs from device to device, but not from application to application on that device.  It sounds like you were expecting different devices to share the same /proc/cpuinfo file, which will never be the case.

I hope that helps!